# Returning One Column From A Table

Tags: python, astronomy

I am conducting astronomy and am dealing with large data sets. I am looking to write a code that will return me one column from a table (so just *fuv_flux*) as an example. Right now I have code that returns the entire table:

```
import sys
with open('/d/acadia/smartens/Group 12958') as file:
    for line in file:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Looking for a way I could tweak this slightly to only return a single column. It should also order them from greatest to least. Would I just use `list.sort(x)` for that? Sample table data as below.

```
matched_id          fuv_mag       fuv_flux    nuv_mag    nuv_flux      e_bv      g  
2932725303248690104 19.6824     48.64531    19.1775     77.44621    0.04016378  12958   
6382772910356957798 -999        -999        18.55329    137.6206    0.03856962  12958
```

Comment: It all depends on how your data is formatted.

Comment: They are text files that are just tables with column headers, data extracted from large astronomical databases.

Comment: Perhaps you should post a few lines. There is no such thing as a standard table format. The fields might be separated with tabs, commas, or other characters. They might or might not have quotes around them.

Comment: Here are two rows from a nine column table with the headers on top:

Comment: matched_id  fuv_mag  fuv_flux nuv_mag  nuv_flux e_bv  g ra  dec
2932725303248690104 19.6824  48.64531 19.1775  77.44621 0.04016378 12958 227.651917 6.31871
6382772910356957798 -999  -999  18.55329 137.6206 0.03856962 12958 227.850998 6.344164

Comment: you can try using Topcat for stuffs like this instead of writing a program. http://www.star.bris.ac.uk/~mbt/topcat/

Answer (score 0):

> They are text files that are just tables with column headers

I'm guessing you mean CSV files. Do they look something like this?

```
columnName1,columnName2,fuv_flux
1,2,3
3,4,5
```

You could look into the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), but for a simple problem like pulling out one column, you could easily write your own function:

```
def get_column(filename, column_name):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fid:
        header = fid.readline()
        # Figure out which column header matches our column name
        column_index = header.split(',').index(column_name)
        column_data = []
        for line in fid:
            # Get the `column_index`th item from each line
            column_data.append(line.split(',')[column_index])
    return column_data
```

Comment: What do you mean by column_index? What does that mean? Also it is returning a Syntax Error after 'filename' in the definition statement. Are the filename and column name supposed to be in quotation marks?

Comment: Is the column_index just looking fro which column it is (counting from right to left)? Therefore column_3 would be correct? And then when in line six it has just 'index' you would just put '3'?

Comment: Yes, but counting from left to right. `filename` is what we call a "variable", meaning its value depends on what arguments we pass to our `get_column` function. `column_index` is also a "variable", so you shouldn't just change its name, you should let `list.index` assign the value 3 (or `2`, in this case) to it for you.

Comment: So in the code you sent me where is list.index? And where you have column_index, I should have column_2 (or some integer)? what do you mean by do not change the name?

Comment: I think it would help for you to start with a python tutorial. try this: http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/python

Answer (score 0):

For simple procedures like the above (i.e returning just a single column) or making changes to ASCII files, FITS files etc. it is better to use TOPCAT instead of writing a program.

Here is the link http://www.star.bris.ac.uk/~mbt/topcat/

There are many advantages with TOPCAT and a few hours of using it is enough to almost master it. You can modify large data sets within seconds and save it as a new file. You can also do concatenations and also plot your columns easily. I am an Astronomy student myself and I suggest you use it for simple stuffs.

Comment: I am also going to have to run data through algorithms and organize it in certain ways to analyze it. Will TOPCAT be a good option for this as well?

Comment: @Mart.Astro Can you explain briefly what sort of algorithms you are going to run through them? Organizing the data is taken care of by TOPCAT in seconds, you can sort your data as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is nicely formatted with spaces (no tabs), and looks like:

```
matched_id          fuv_mag     fuv_flux    nuv_mag     nuv_flux    e_bv        g
2932725303248690104 19.6824     48.64531    19.1775     77.44621    0.04016378  12958
6382772910356957798 -999        -999        18.55329    137.6206    0.03856962  12958
```

Then this is just a matter of determining the boundaries of each column:

```
import sys
import re
with open('test.txt') as file:
    it = iter(file)
    header_text = next(it)
    offsets = []
    current_offset = 0
    for column_title in re.split(r'(\S+\s+)', header_text):
        if column_title:
            next_offset = current_offset + len(column_title)
            offsets.append((current_offset, next_offset))
            current_offset = next_offset
    offsets[-1] = (offsets[-1][0], -1)
    for line in it:
        if len(line) < offsets[-1][0]:
            continue
        split_line = [ line[begin:end] .strip() for begin, end in offsets]
        print(split_line)
```

However, if you can be certain that no data-cell, in the rows below, contains spaces, and that spaces are valid delimiters, then things can be slightly simpler:

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        split_line = re.split(r'\s+', line.rstrip())
        print(split_line)
```

Since you want only the column of fuv_flux, which is of index 2, then you can simplify the above two solutions to

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
    it = iter(file)
    header_text = next(it)
    m = re.search(r'^((?:\S+\s+){2})(\S+\s+)', header_text.rstrip())
    offsets = []
    begin = len(m.group(1))
    end = begin + len(m.group(2))
    for line in it:
        if len(line) < end:
            continue
        print(line[begin:end])
```

And

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
   for line in file:
      m = re.search(r'^(?:\S+\s+){2}(\S+)', line.rstrip())
      if m:
          print(m.group(1))
```

But I'd go for the first two alternatives that generate a list, since it is more flexible.